# how to move selected data from one datagridview in form1 to another datagridview in form2

Tags: vb.net

I am using vb.net with MS access. I have a datagridview1 in form1 and I want copy selected row to another datagridview2 in form, using copy button. after copying the selected data from datagridview1 is being deleted by following code. But I don't know how to copy the data.

```
Private Sub BindingNavigatorDeleteItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object,
        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BindingNavigatorDeleteItem.Click

    Me.Validate()

    Me.HPReportBindingSource.AllowRemove.ToString()

     Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.Histopathology_NewDataSet1)

     MsgBox("Saved")

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the 2 datagridviews have the same column count

```
Private Sub BindingNavigatorDeleteItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, 
        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BindingNavigatorDeleteItem.Click
    If DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then
        Dim selectedgrid As DataGridViewRow = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0)
        DataGridView1.Rows.Remove(selectedgrid)
        DataGridView2.Rows.Add(selectedgrid)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Sir I have DataGridView2 in Form2, so there an error is coming like DataGridView2 is not declared.

Comment: IF I add the DataGridView2 to same form1 then following error came-"Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound"

Comment: I am using databindernavigation to retrieve data from table of MS access

Comment: If you are using MS access, i think you should you the remove and insert to modify the database.

Comment: I am using MS access. How can i remove and insert the database?